# MVC3 Performance on a Large scale website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to know if anyone suggests developing a large scale website with ASP.Net MVC3.
By large scale i mean about 3000,000 requests per day.

Comment: You've asked your question on arguably the largest MVC website out there :) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 2):

That's not so much. We have a web site running on two servers handling about 8,000,000 requests each per day, and that doesn't even use 10% of the capacity.

So, yes, ASP.NET MVC certainly works for that scale of site.